# "Conroller as" with ng-repeat with array of objects (does not work with 'this')

Tags: angularjs

I noticed that for me this shows nothing in `ng-repeat`:

```
 <ul ng-controller="UserCtrl as ctrl">
        <li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">
           <a href="#/user/{{user.id}}/view">{{user.name}}</a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

But this, works ok:

```
 <ul ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
           <a href="#/user/{{user.id}}/view">{{user.name}}</a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

Why is that?

My Controller code is simple as that:

```
angular.module('main.controllers').controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserResource', function UserCtrl($scope, UserResource) {

    $scope.users = UserResource.list();  // works with $resource service

    // ideally I would like type "var users = ..." without using $scope

    var ctrl = this;

    this.users = function() {
        return UserResource.list();
    };
    return this;

}
```

where users are json array of objects I'm eventually getting as resolved promise result:

```
[ 
  { id: "1", name: "name1" },
  { id: "2", name: "name2" },
  { id: "3", name: "name3" }
]
```

**Update:**
 The whole point is that it does not work with `this.users` and `controller-as` notation when it is wrapped in promise that I'm getting from $resource service.

```
return $resource(' /rest/user-api/user/:id/:action',
    {id: "@id"}, //parameters default
    {
        list: { method: "GET", params: {action : "list"}, isArray: true},
    });
```

Comment: WHat happens when you try `<li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users()">` You basically need to invoke the function users right? However you just need to do `this.users = UserResource.list()` and use the way you have it

Comment: @PSL in this case it shows nothing. I feel it works only if I pass $scope-d variable to the ng-repeat.

Comment: yep. I have a feeling that that is related to _arrays_ of object. When it is just an object, then it works.

Comment: It does not matter if it works with `$scope.users = ..` it should work with `this.users=..` as well. Underneath resource returns an object reference which gets updated after the call is resolved interally.

Comment: maybe it is a bug then.

Comment: Here is an example with proper usage of resource, see it working. http://plnkr.co/edit/uVFYecZqezfFgsLDEIIp?p=preview Your issue is else where. What error do you see in your console? also have you configured the `list` to return as array?

Comment: See my reply to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

In you controller you've got

```
this.users = function() ..
```

so in you view you need to execute that function to get users

```
  <li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users()">
```

`this.users` should be rather array like in my demo `this.users2` and in that case you can use it in repeater as

```
<li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users2">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').service("userService", function($timeout, $q) {

  this.getData = function() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {


      var arr = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Jack from Service"
      }];

      deffered.resolve(arr);


    }, 2000);

    return deffered.promise;
  };

  return this;
});

angular.module('app').controller('UserCtrl', ['userService',

  function UserCtrl(userService) {

    // ideally I would like type "var users = ..." without using $scope

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.users = function() {
      return [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Jack Function"
      }];
    };

    ctrl.users2 = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Jack Array"
    }];


    ////// users from service 

    this.usersFromService = [];

    function activate() {
      userService.getData().then(function(data) {
        angular.copy(data, ctrl.usersFromService);
      });
    }
    activate();


    return this;

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="UserCtrl as ctrl">

   

    <li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users2">
      <a href="#/user/{{user.id}}/view">{{user.name}}</a>
    </li>

    <li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.usersFromService">
      <a href="#/user/{{user.id}}/view">{{user.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: yep, has nothing to do with the controller as syntax, it is the way the data is generated that's the problem.

Comment: In your demo array of object come Not from defer object that then returns as resolved promise of array of objects, like in my case.

Comment: @ses I've updated my answer please have a look how you can get data from defer object

Comment: @sylwesyer I will try, it seems it looks like that what I have started from.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that:

When I do this:

```
<ul ng-controller="UserCtrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="user in ctr.users">
```

It does not work.

When I do this:

```
<ul ng-controller="UserCtrl as userCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="user in userCtrl.users">
```

or `UserCtrl as a` or `UserCtrl as b` ... - it works.

I just does not like `ctrl` as a name.

Thanks to all who were not voting "close". I can NOT explain how it differs from that I got as replies. In my case I use end-to end angular - `NodeJS` application that actually does whole client-server communication. Not sure it matters.

Maybe it clashes with another scopes.. I'm not sure yet. But the general advice - try to change the name after "as" and see what happen If you have issue like that. I know it's weird.

Comment: This makes no sense, In your first line you are defining alias as ctrl and in the next line you are trying to use it as `ctr.users` instead of `ctrl.users`. Even if it is a typo in your answer, there is no restriction on the alias, since they are mere property names which will be attached to the scope and will have the instance of the controller. Probably see if you are using the same alias (`ctrl`) anywhere else in the scope chain, I would recommend reduce your code to minimal and find out the real issue..

Comment: I'm planning to do this. To pinpoint it. If not will share that minimum that I can share to GitHub prove that I have this issue.